# error: Invalid face, org-level-1

Tags: org-mode, faces

```lisp
(dolist (face '((org-level-1 . 1.2)
                (org-level-2 . 1.1)
                (org-level-3 . 1.05)
                (org-level-4 . 1.0)
                (org-level-5 . 1.1)
                (org-level-6 . 1.1)
                (org-level-7 . 1.1)
                (org-level-8 . 1.1)))
  (set-face-attribute (car face) nil :font "Cantarell" :weight 'regular :height (cdr face)))
```

when I evaluate this code, emacs doesn't complain but when I load a new instance of emacs it gives me an error of: `error: Invalid face, org-level-1`.

emacs: v27.1, org: v9.3

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that in an `(with-eval-after-load 'org-faces ...)`?

Comment: yeah that worked. Thanks man! I should start learn elisp. May you explain why this happened in the answer? I copied this code from a tutorial in youtube (system crafters), probably a few other people may encountered this problem and this will be helpful for them. I created an issue in the corresponding [repository](https://github.com/daviwil/emacs-from-scratch/issues/34). I will share this answer there.

Comment: @lawlist: Please look for a duplicate... OP or lawlist: if this is not a duplicate, please provide the answer as an answer, not just as a comment. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: please feel free to edit the title and the question because I 'feel' this answer is not specific to the question and the title. thank you again lawlist for explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message `Invalid face` comes from an internal C function `lface_from_face_name_no_resolve` within `xfaces.c`  A face must be defined before an attribute thereof may be changed with `set-face-attribute`.  The library that defines the `org-level-...` faces is named `org-faces`, with the Lisp version being `org-faces.el` and the byte-compiled version being `org-faces.elc`.  The main library of `org-mode` is `org.el`, and it expressly calls the `org-faces` library with the line `(require 'org-faces)`.  The function `with-eval-after-load` (see the doc string of the function with `C-h f with-eval-after-load` and the [Elisp Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html#index-with_002deval_002dafter_002dload) for more details) can be used to ensure the `org-faces` library is loaded before attributes of faces defined therein are changed:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-faces ...)
```

The `dolist` statement proposed by the O.P. can be inserted/replaced in lieu of the `...` hereinabove.  The second argument to `with-eval-after-load` is looking for BODY, which is interpreted to mean just one form ... Where more than one statement is required, consider using `(progn ...)` to wrap one or more statements; e.g., `(progn [SOMETHING] [SOMETHING ELSE])`